# How do I go to the original page?

Tags: amp-html

Sorry; end user here. I didn't see where else to ask.

AMP is pretty slick, but often I'll want to go to the original webpage; perhaps the formatting is better, or perhaps I want to share the article and don't want Google's domain name in front. I would expect that tapping on the name of the original site in the bar at the top of the page would do that, or if not, the close "x", but neither of those seem to work. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you referring to using hyperlinks to go to the original page? What do you mean? Can you share code to support your question?

Comment: Yes, there should be a hyperlink on each AMP page that goes to the original page. In Google AMP, there is a header bar that includes the domain name of the original site, but tapping it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the "full" page, then you need to go to the canonical version of the page. By viewing the source, you'll see, for example...

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/story" />
```

...and that will be the full version of the page.

There's no requirement for site owners to make this link visible otherwise, so you probably won't see it in an app to click on.

Comment: However, it looks like Google at least has added the ability to go to the original page Thierry a "link" icon.